# CGImageSourceCreateThumbnailAtIndex crashes with 20MB Image

Tags: ios, objective-c, image

The following method for creating a thumbnail image crashes on an iPad when I test it with large images (ie > 10 MB). I've profiled it and Allocations doesn't report any large memory spikes - it stays consistently at 5 MB of living memory during the operation.

How can I create a thumbnail for an image so large? I've tried scaling it with Core Graphics but that is less memory efficient and doesn't work.

```
+(UIImage*) thumbnailImageAtPath:(NSString*) path withSize:(CGSize) size{

    @autoreleasepool{

        CGImageSourceRef src = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL((__bridge CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path], NULL);

        if(!src){
            return nil;
        }

        NSDictionary* options = @{
                                  (id)kCGImageSourceShouldAllowFloat : (id)kCFBooleanTrue,
                                  (id)kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailWithTransform : (id)kCFBooleanFalse,
                                  (id)kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailFromImageIfAbsent : (id)kCFBooleanTrue,
                                  (id)kCGImageSourceThumbnailMaxPixelSize : [NSNumber numberWithDouble:1024]
                                  };

        CGImageRef thumbnail = CGImageSourceCreateThumbnailAtIndex(src, 0, (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)options);

        // Doesn't reach here :(

        UIImage* img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:thumbnail];

        NSLog(@"Size: %f, %f", size.width, size.height);

        CGImageRelease(thumbnail);
        CFRelease(src);

        return img;

    }

}
```

I've tried it on the main thread, worker threads, concurrently, non-concurrently, etc - it just doesn't seem to work on an actual device.

What's also strange is that it works brilliantly with a PDF of > 60 MB.

Comment: A few questions 1) what's the crash, exactly? 2) can you host a problematic image? I don't have any extremely large images on hand 3) what device and iOS version? Thanks!

Comment: 1) It just stops - no memory warnings or exceptions
2) The problem occurs with any image seemly in access of 10MB.. try this one http://cdn.hdwallpaperspics.com/uploads/2012/11/iceHD_hires.jpg
3) iPad mini iOS 6, I should note that I've only tried it on this device and an emulator because this is the lowest spec device the app will run on

Comment: Running this code on an iPad Mini with iOS 6.1.3, with that image, works fine. I'm passing a size of `{100,100}`. Can you explain more about the context? Also could you explain more by 'just stops'? Does it hang? Are there any crash logs produced? EDIT: I should note that wallpaper is only 10 megs. I'm looking for a larger one but if you could host one that would be a help. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, for another update - I did find an 18 megabyte jpg on wikipedia. Passing sizes of 100*100, 40*40, and 20*20 has so far seemed slower but hasn't crashed or hung. Of course, now that I look closer at the code, it only logs the size. I think some context is missing from your question that would help reproduce the problem.

Comment: There are no logs, no hangs, nothing. It just stops. I've profiled it and there are no abnormal memory spikes in Instruments. I've passed sizes of both 200x200 and 100x100 and it crashes with both.

In terms of context: its a PNG file (should this make a difference?) and the 'thumbnail creation' method is called in an operation and run in a non-concurrent background queue. I had to do this because the UI hung if I generated the thumbnail on the main thread.

Thanks for your help btw:)

Comment: It still runs fine with a 32 meg png (the 21600 * 21600 image [here](http://visibleearth.nasa.gov/view.php?id=74393)) and running it in a block passed to `dispatch_async()`. There's something else going on here. Can you try to reproduce the problem in a fresh project to narrow down the cause?

Comment: I agree to @CarlVeazey - I tried your code on the image you provided with first generation iPad - and it runs fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove option kCGImageSourceThumbnailMaxPixelSize... Ask me if not.

EDIT:
Try this code:

```
+ (UIImage*)scaleAndRotateImage:(UIImage *)image{

int kMaxResolution = 1024; // Or whatever 320

CGImageRef imgRef = image.CGImage;

CGFloat width;
CGFloat height;

width = CGImageGetWidth(imgRef);
height = CGImageGetHeight(imgRef);

CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
CGRect bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height);
if (width > kMaxResolution || height > kMaxResolution) {
    CGFloat ratio = width/height;
    if (ratio > 1) {
        bounds.size.width = kMaxResolution;
        bounds.size.height = bounds.size.width / ratio;
    }
    else {
        bounds.size.height = kMaxResolution;
        bounds.size.width = bounds.size.height * ratio;
    }
}

CGFloat scaleRatio = bounds.size.width / width;
CGSize imageSize = CGSizeMake(CGImageGetWidth(imgRef), CGImageGetHeight(imgRef));
CGFloat boundHeight;
UIImageOrientation orient = image.imageOrientation;
switch(orient) {

    case UIImageOrientationUp: //EXIF = 1
        transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
        break;

    case UIImageOrientationUpMirrored: //EXIF = 2
        transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(imageSize.width, 0.0);
        transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1.0, 1.0);
        break;

    case UIImageOrientationDown: //EXIF = 3
        transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(imageSize.width, imageSize.height);
        transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI);
        break;

    case UIImageOrientationDownMirrored: //EXIF = 4
        transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, imageSize.height);
        transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, 1.0, -1.0);
        break;

    case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored: //EXIF = 5
        boundHeight = bounds.size.height;
        bounds.size.height = bounds.size.width;
        bounds.size.width = boundHeight;
        transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(imageSize.height, imageSize.width);
        transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1.0, 1.0);
        transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, 3.0 * M_PI / 2.0);
        break;

    case UIImageOrientationLeft: //EXIF = 6
        boundHeight = bounds.size.height;
        bounds.size.height = bounds.size.width;
        bounds.size.width = boundHeight;
        transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, imageSize.width);
        transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, 3.0 * M_PI / 2.0);
        break;

    case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored: //EXIF = 7
        boundHeight = bounds.size.height;
        bounds.size.height = bounds.size.width;
        bounds.size.width = boundHeight;
        transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1.0, 1.0);
        transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI / 2.0);
        break;

    case UIImageOrientationRight: //EXIF = 8
        boundHeight = bounds.size.height;
        bounds.size.height = bounds.size.width;
        bounds.size.width = boundHeight;
        transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(imageSize.height, 0.0);
        transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI / 2.0);
        break;

    default:
        [NSException raise:NSInternalInconsistencyException format:@"Invalid image orientation"];

}

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(bounds.size);

CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

if (orient == UIImageOrientationRight || orient == UIImageOrientationLeft) {
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, -scaleRatio, scaleRatio);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -height, 0);
}
else {
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, scaleRatio, -scaleRatio);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, -height);
}

CGContextConcatCTM(context, transform);

CGContextDrawImage(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), imgRef);
UIImage *imageCopy = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return imageCopy;}
```

Comment: That didn't work - it continued to crash and spat out memory warnings for all the other thumbnails its loading.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* I know what the issue was.

The png that I was using had quite a few alpha transparent pixels in it.

I'll have to run some definitive tests with different alpha/non-alpha images to confirm that was the problem, though. Will do that when I get a chance.

Answer (score -1):

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"LARGE_elevation" ofType:@"jpg"];

UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
image = [self scaleImage:image toSize:CGSizeMake(400, 200)];

- (UIImage *)scaleImage:(UIImage *)image
                        toSize:(CGSize)size
{
    CGSize sz = image.size;
    if(sz.width > size.width || sz.height > size.height) {
        double ratio = MIN(sz.width / size.width, sz.height / size.height);
        sz.width /= ratio;
        sz.height /= ratio;
    }
    CGContextRef context;
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO, image.scale);
    context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetGrayFillColor(context, 0.0, 1.0);
    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height));
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, sz.width, sz.height)];
    UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```

LARGE_elevation.jpg - 14.3 mb.

Comment: this is not memory efficient as you are loading entire image to the memory.